# Different output based on the way I invoke a get() method

Tags: java, queue, getmethod

Given the below code in the `main()` method when calling `get()` method in class `Queue` the output differs when I do this in a way put forward below:

**All letters shown in the output of this code as expected** :

```
class Queue {
    char get() {
        if (getlock == putlock) {
            System.out.println("-Queue is empty");
            return (char) 0;
        }
        return q[getlock++];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue bigQ = new Queue(100);
    Queue smallQ = new Queue(4);

    char ch;
    int i;

    System.out.println("Using bigQ to store the alphabet. ");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        bigQ.put((char)('A' + i));

    System.out.print("Contents of bigQ: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        ch = bigQ.get();
        if (ch != (char) 0)
            System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
```

However, when I don't use `char ch` in the `main()` but instead repeatedly call `bigQ.get()` directly, it shows only every third letter. I am tired and cannot understand why. The changed fragment of code is below:

**Only every third letters is shown in the output of this code**

```
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        bigQ.get(); 
        if (bigQ.get() != (char) 0)     
            System.out.print(bigQ.get());
    }
```

Small change and such a difference. I would be grateful if you would let me know why this is, because I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get` method is destructive. Every time it's called the queue advances one - the `getlock++` piece of code. In your altered code snippet you call `get` three times every iteration, discarding two of the results.

Unlike English, `get` in Java is usually reserved for methods that do not alter state (except in JSF). `java.util.Queue` uses `poll`, whilst `remove` will throw an exception if the queue is empty. `take` is also a popular choice for this sort of method.